# How to find location of subviews in a custom layout

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've got a View with a custom layout I implemented. This works great and I'm doing something like this (simplified):

```swift
struct SomeContent: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        WheelLayout {
            ForEach(targets, id: \.self) {
                app in
                VStack {
                    app.icon != nil ? Image(nsImage: app.icon!) : Image(systemName: "rectangle.dashed")
                    Text(app.name).bold()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But now I'd like to know which `app` icon is the closest to the mouse cursor.

I expect part of the solution is to replace that `VStack` with a new specific class of `View` which holds the reference to the `app` itself. But now, in the code inside the window which contains `SomeContent` - how would I query for something like "list of all subviews of that class" so I can check their positions?

Comment: I, usually, use "preferences" (and GeometryReader) for things like that. This article was very helpful to me back in the day: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/15/the-magic-of-view-preferences-in-swiftui/. Let me know if you need an example.